# Distinct clause causing type error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Trying to do a .Distinct() clause in ASP.net MVC Entity Framework, but getting an error on the following code:

```
var tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans = db.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans.Include(t => t.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffTime).OrderBy(t => t.StartBan).Take(10).Select(t => t.UserID).Distinct();
```

The error is:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item
>   passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Dashboard.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBan]'.

`t => t.UserID` is an Int, but is shown on the page as a Username + First & Last Name. Any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I suspect that you are specifying the wrong model type in the `@model` declaration in the view and are passing something of a different type, probably through the `return View(myModel)`... they have to be exactly matching

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're selecting the user ID (resulting in a sequence of user IDs) and then calling `Distinct`on that. The result is still a sequence of user IDs... whereas it looks like your page wants a sequence of `tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBan`. I suspect you want to keep the whole entity, but just make them distinct *by* user ID. That's most easily done with grouping:

```
 var tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans = db.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBans
    .Include(t => t.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffTime)
    .OrderBy(t => t.StartBan)
    .GroupBy(t => t.UserID)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Take(10);
```

Note that I've moved the grouping to *before* the `Take(10)`, with the assumption that you want the first 10 users rather than the first 10 bans *then* grouped by user. (Are you sure you don't want `OrderByDescending` in order to show the most *recent* bans?)

Comment: This worked perfectly, but changed (g => g.First()) to (g => g.FirstOrDefault()). Yeah, it'll be ordered by most recent bans, but also going to find a way to display bans so that only ones where the expiry date is after or equal to todays date is shown.

Comment: @ChrisBarsby: Why would you use `FirstOrDefault`? That would suggest you're trying to consider a situation where there's an empty group - but `GroupBy` will never produce an empty group. And as for "only ones where the expiry date is after or equal to today's date" - that's just a `Where` call, and has nothing to do with the ordering...

Answer (score 0):

Problem arguably is that your view is waiting for a Model of type `List<Dashboard.tblGlobalLogOnLogOffStudentBan>`, but you are sending instead a `IEnumerable` of `Int32` type created by your LINQ `Select()` selection.

Assuming that's the case, the solution would be change the view `@model` to a `List` of `Int32`.

Comment: That would only be the solution if the view could actually do its work based solely on the user IDs. I suspect it can't.

Comment: Absolutely. the OP knows best what he really needs but I also assume he would want more since he's talking about Username + First & Last name. Your answer rocks (as always) :)